# I cannot put false in the database table

Tags: php, database, postgresql, zend-framework

I have a problem.I have a boolean column in the table, and I cannot put a FALSE value into it, e.g.

```
$privilege->update(array('deleted' => false));
```

when i try set false,i have such an error as if i tried to insert null:

Message: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: empty value in "allow" ... (2915, 65, 1, f, null)., query was: UPDATE "Actions" SET "allow" = ? WHERE ("Actions" ."id" = 2915)

,but I can put TRUE value without any problem e.g.:

```
$privilege->update(array('usunieta' => true));
```

Why?

Here is my functions:

```
public function delete($id) {
$role = $this->getModel($id);
$role->id_statusy = $this->getStatusId('deleted');
$this->getDataSource()->beginTransaction();
foreach ($role->getPrivileges() as $privilege) {
    $privilege->update(array('deleted' => true));   //problem with this line, when 'deleted' => false
}
foreach ($role->getUsers() as $user) {
    $user->delete();
}
$this->getDataSource()->save($role);
$this->getDataSource()->commit();
```

}

And

```
    public function update(array $data, $id) {
    $role = $this->getModel($id);
    $role->setFromArray($data);
    $this->getDataSource()->beginTransaction();
    $this->getDataSource()->save($role);
    $this->getDataSource()->commit();
}
```

Comment: Whatever obfuscation you have going on, you will have to dig into to find the real reason why its trying to set a null instead of a false. Proper use of prepared statements and variables would not cause this issue. Like, who the hell knows what `$role->setFromArray($data);` does.

Comment: dude, just set the column in DB to be tinyint and set your updated data to be either 1 or 0

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere in your DBAL there's a "if(!$value){$value = null}` or similar

Comment: @IncredibleHat probably anyone familiar with the [Zend-framework](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_Db_Table_Row.html) since `setFromArray` is a built in method for that framework, no?    `Sets all data in the row from an array.`

Comment: Looking at ZF1 (not sure what version you're using), the value eventually gets concatenated as a string in DB/Adapter/Abstract.php, so if it's true, it becomes a 1, and if it's false it becomes null. Pass in a zero.